# Glyph origin for 㐆 and Mnemonic for 殷

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

Came across through the word 殷勤. could you please help with Glyph origin for :

㐆yǐn to follow, to trust to, to put confidence in, to depend on, to turn around

Any any mnemonic to remember this?

殷 yīn earnest, eager, flourishing, hospitable
yǐn roll of thunder
yān dark red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

㐆 is a reversed 身 which could be a rotund man or pregnant woman, likely the latter in this context. I've never seen 㐆 being used alone before.

殷 is grand, abundant, or flourish. Getting pregnant with child would be a source of celebration back then, and 殳 represents a hand hitting something, likely a drum if we were to interpret the original meaning as "grand music."

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AE%B7